# How to Efficiently Manage Large Datasets in Select2 with AJAX and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, large-data, jquery-select2-4

I'm working on a Laravel application that requires dynamic loading of select options in the UI, potentially dealing with large datasets. The goal is to implement autocomplete functionality where options are filtered based on user input. I'm considering factors like pagination, search direction, and active state control for efficiency and user experience.

1. **How can I implement pagination and offset handling for large
   datasets?**
2. **Is there a way to configure the search direction (left-to-right or
   right-to-left) based on user settings?**
3. **Can I control which options are available based on their active**
4. **What's the best practice for adding additional query customizations
   for specific application logic?
   state?**
5. **Lastly, how can I ensure that this solution is easily reusable
   across different models or controllers in my Laravel application?**

Comment: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax . You can have it search the server for options rather than pre-loading the entire dataset. Other than that, it's a bit unclear what your specific problem / issue is? See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your problem.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to post a question. i have miss content

Comment: Try not to post your question before it's finished, in future! Now you can go back and [edit] it though

Comment: I have written my complete question.

Comment: No, you've written 5 questions, which isn't allowed. You must focus on one specific issue, which can't be anything attracting an opinion (such as question 4 asking for "best practice") or too broad / vague (such as question 5), or anything which is likely to be answerable by reading the documentation and giving it a try (such as questions 2 and 3). And question 1 is pretty generic - pagination of results in an API is no doubt well-documented online with many approaches, designs etc available. Did you read [ask]? What have you researched and tried so far? Where are you stuck, _specifically_?

Comment: Okay, give me some time I will share my code here.

Comment: Nobody said they didn't understand it. Read my comments again. I see you haven't edited anything yet, despite promising to. Instead of getting angry with us, just fix your post.

Comment: I explained the problems with your post already. Is there something specific you're unsure about? P.S. Who is "bro"? You can't assume all programmers are a "bro" - are they all male, in your view?? I am not bothered by this but, as a friendly point, I would suggest that you simply refer to users here by their username, so that you don't accidentally label people as something they're not, and thereby offend them. :-)

Comment: P.S. `how do you vote negatively if you don't understand it`...well, I didn't say it wasn't understandable, but if it _was_ difficult to understand then that would be a valid reason to downvote it actually. Hover your mouse over the downvote button on any question and you will seem some of the possible downvoting reasons listed...one of which is that the question is "unclear". You can also read more about downvoting at https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 1):

hi you can`t show lots of data on select2 and it better to search in records and filter the result in server side and Controller than show on select2.

for this purpose you should send 'ajax' to server and in you method get 'term'

```
$term = $request->term;
```

for send 'ajax'can use this function for search with "select2" :

```
function init_select2_ajax(selector, url, placeholder) {
    placeholder = placeholder || "...";
    url = url || '/';
    $(selector).select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        dir: "rtl",
        width: "100%",
        placeholder: placeholder,
        language: "fa",
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            quietMillis: 150,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.text,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
}
```